# Not able to change "maxClauseCount" value in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am using ES 5.2.0 and I got below exception during some query execution:

```
 Caused by: NotSerializableExceptionWrapper[too_many_clauses: maxClauseCount is set to 1024]
    at org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery$Builder.add(BooleanQuery.java:125)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.BoolQueryBuilder.addBooleanClauses(BoolQueryBuilder.java:449)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.BoolQueryBuilder.doToQuery(BoolQueryBuilder.java:418)
```

To solve this. I am trying to change "indices.query.bool.max_clause_count" value by running below query

Request:

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings?preserve_existing=true  
{"indices.query.bool.max_clause_count" : "100000"}
```

Response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "remote_transport_exception",
        "reason": "[06LrSZC][localhost:9300][indices:admin/settings/update]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "unknown setting [index.indices.query.bool.max_clause_count] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

References I used to solve but couldn't:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/breaking_50_settings_changes.html#_search_settings

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/5-0-0-alpha2-how-to-set-index-query-bool-max-clause-count/49816

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/18341

Please let me know the correct request JSON to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`indices.query.bool.max_clause_count` is a static setting so you should set it in `elasticsearch.yml` file in each and every node of elasticsearch cluster. You must restart the cluster.

Update your `elasticsearch.yml` file with following line:

```
indices.query.bool.max_clause_count: 100000
```

**Note**: Only dynamic settings can be updated with API

Answer (score 1):

That is a global setting, not index level one and its place is in `elasticsearch.yml` file:

```
indices.query.bool.max_clause_count: 10000
```

That's why it was also renamed from `index` (singular) to `indices` (plural).

Answer (score 1):

Another possibly better way to look at list is just reduce the amount of mustNots to a single must not with multiple terms. This will count as a single mustNot and it will not trigger the exception, allowing you to keep the limit of Clauses which might be required in other places in your application.
For example 
the code above will get a list of airportCode and "mustNot" them one at a time

```
// adding the blacklisted carriers to the query
BannedAirportCodeCache.instance().getAirportCodes()
    .forEach(airportCode-> boolQueryBuilder.mustNot(QueryBuilders
        .matchQuery("airportcodes.raw", airportCode)));
```

Whereas the code above will do the same but in a single mustNot, and it wont trigger the tooManyClauses

```
QueryBuilder termsQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders
    .termsQuery("airportcodes.raw", BannedAirportCodeCache.instance().getAirportCodes());
boolQueryBuilder.mustNot(termsQueryBuilder);
```